# @Startup @Singleton Java annotations not working (TomEE 8 Web Profile + CentOS 7)

Tags: java, centos, singleton, ejb, startup

Trying to deploy web application on TomEE Web Edition 8.0.0-M3 (CentOS7, JDK12) - everything works, but for some reason `@Startup` `@Singleton` annotations not working - `start()` and `destroy()` methods are not called.

```
package test;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class SessionManager {

        @PostConstruct
        public void start() {
            System.out.println("PostConstruct");
        }

        @PreDestroy
        public void destroy() {
            System.out.println("PreDestroy");
        }
    }
```

On Win10 it works. When starting TomEE I can see that it loads openejb:

```
(...)    
24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.020 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.jdbc.datasource-creator=org.apache.tomee.jdbc.TomEEDataSourceCreator'
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> ********************************************************************************
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> OpenEJB http://tomee.apache.org/
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Startup: Wed Jul 24 04:48:49 EEST 2019
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Copyright 1999-2018 (C) Apache OpenEJB Project, All Rights Reserved.
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Version: 8.0.0-M3
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Build date: 20190523
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> Build time: 12:13
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> ********************************************************************************
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> openejb.home = C:\opt\apache-tomee-webprofile-8.0.0-M3
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init> openejb.base = C:\opt\apache-tomee-webprofile-8.0.0-M3
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Created new singletonService org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl@10993713
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.104 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.initializeOWB Succeeded in installing singleton service
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.135 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.init TomEE configuration file is 'C:\opt\apache-tomee-webprofile-8.0.0-M3\conf\tomee.xml'
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.173 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Tomcat Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Tomcat Security Service)
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.173 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureService Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.189 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog.info Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath=false'
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.189 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.220 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.320 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager.initServer Creating ServerService(id=cxf-rs)
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.452 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start   ** Bound Services **
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.452 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.printRow   NAME                 IP              PORT  
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.452 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start -------
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.452 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start Ready!
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.452 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Server initialization in [1,552] milliseconds
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.490 INFO [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBNamingContextListener.bindResource Importing a Tomcat Resource with id 'UserDatabase' of type 'org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase'.
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.490 INFO [main] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createRecipe Creating Resource(id=UserDatabase)
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.505 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting service [Catalina]
    24-Jul-2019 04:48:49.505 INFO [main] jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.20]
(...)
```

But not on CentOS.. TomEE versions and configuration identical, strange..

Downloaded TomEE plus - now it's working as expected. So it seems like TomEE webprofile version does not support EJBs??

Answer (score 0):

It does but it seems your EJB does not have start/destroy methods, the nested class not being an EJB you end up with an empty EJB and an unmanaged class with an ignored lifecycle.

Can you drop SessionManager class and move start/destroy in NewClass?

Romain

Comment: I've updated the code (made a mistake at midnight..:). After installing TomEE Plus - the application started. Perhaps TomEE Web Profile does not support EJB? And another problem - if I'm trying to start the second application which has the same class `SessionManager` - it fails to start. After I changed class name of one of them - both started normally.  I didn't had such problem on Glassfish. Seems that `@Startup`, `@Sigleton` class names should be unique.

Comment: By default yes, it must be unique. Try setting in conf/system.properties: openejb.deploymentId.format={appId}/{ejbJarId}/{ejbName}. Should solve it. Web profile clearly supports EJB perfectly and even passes TCK :).